# Conda doesn't find existent binstar package

Tags: python, installation, package, anaconda, binstar

I'm trying to install the hdf5storage package for my Python 3 installation on a 64-Bit Windows 8 machine using Anaconda.
Just to make sure that everything was up to date, I did a

```
C:\Users\Baeuerle>conda install binstar
Fetching package metadata: ..
Solving package specifications: .
Package plan for installation in environment C:\Anaconda3:

The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    binstar-0.9.4              |           py34_0         115 KB
    clyent-0.3.2               |           py34_0          13 KB
    conda-3.7.3                |           py34_0         202 KB
    pytz-2014.9                |           py34_0         167 KB
    requests-2.4.3             |           py34_0         607 KB
    setuptools-7.0             |           py34_0         749 KB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:         1.8 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    clyent:     0.3.2-py34_0

The following packages will be UPDATED:

    binstar:    0.7.1-py34_0  --> 0.9.4-py34_0
    conda:      3.7.0-py34_0  --> 3.7.3-py34_0
    pytz:       2014.7-py34_0 --> 2014.9-py34_0
    requests:   2.4.1-py34_0  --> 2.4.3-py34_0
    setuptools: 5.8-py34_0    --> 7.0-py34_0

Proceed ([y]/n)?

Fetching packages ...
binstar-0.9.4- 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:01 109.73 kB/s
clyent-0.3.2-p 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00  25.88 kB/s
conda-3.7.3-py 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:05  39.58 kB/s
pytz-2014.9-py 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00 179.44 kB/s
requests-2.4.3 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:02 210.03 kB/s
setuptools-7.0 100% |###############################| Time: 0:01:30   8.45 kB/s
setuptools-7.0 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:03 216.41 kB/s
Extracting packages ...
[      COMPLETE      ] |#################################################| 100%
Unlinking packages ...
[      COMPLETE      ] |#################################################| 100%
Linking packages ...
[      COMPLETE      ] |#################################################| 100%
```

first. Then I did:

```
C:\Users\Baeuerle>binstar show auto/hdf5storage
Using binstar api site https://api.binstar.org
Name:    hdf5storage
Summary: https://github.com/frejanordsiek/hdf5storage
Access:  public
Package Types:  conda
Versions:
   + 0.1.1

To install this package with conda run:
     conda install --channel https://conda.binstar.org/auto hdf5storage

C:\Users\Baeuerle>conda install --channel https://conda.binstar.org/auto hdf5storage
Fetching package metadata: ...
Error: No packages found in current win-64 channels matching: hdf5storage

You can search for this package on Binstar with

    binstar search -t conda hdf5storage

C:\Users\Baeuerle>
```

So what's the problem here? Obviously the package is there and I used the recommended command. Why can't conda find it then? Is this an 64-bit issue and if so what would be the best way to install hdf5storage through anaconda?

Comment: The `auto` channel only has packages for Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem with the graph-tool package and the sigcpp dependency. I'm on osx Yosemite 10.10.

I wanted to install graph-tool. Found the right package for osX on binstar.

```
conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/vgauthier graph-tool
```

and always had the following message

```
Error: Could not find some dependencies for graph-tool: sigcpp
```

Although sigcpp was already installed

```
conda install sigcpp
Fetching package metadata: ..........
Solving package specifications: .
# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at /Users/aperrier/anaconda/envs/py34:
#
sigcpp                    2.3.1                         2
```

What ended up working is to add the channel first to conda and then to install sigcpp and graph-tool

```
conda config --add channels https://conda.binstar.org/cyclus
conda install sigcpp
```

Was told that the package was already existing.
However then graph-tool install worked

```
conda config --add channels https://conda.binstar.org/vgauthier
conda install graph-tool
```

And I was able to finally import graph_tool in ipython

This makes no sense to me but maybe that will help someone with the same problem.

Comment: having a problem installing graph-tool on my macbook. I'm using conda. When following the above I get an Errort:  The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - graph-tool 2.16*
  - python 2.7*

Comment: i also tried graph-tool without =2.16, same error. 2.18 is not found for osX.